# Geometric interpretation of the solution of the complex equation $z^4+z+2=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

> **Question Statement:-**
>
> If $z$ is a complex number such that $z^4+z+2=0$, show that $z$ cannot lie in the interior of the circle $|z|=1$

---

**Attempt at a solution :-**

We are given with the equation $z^4+z+2=0$, so we can write

$$z^4+z+2=0\implies z^4+z=-2 \implies |z^4+z|=2$$

Now, from triangle inequality we get

$$|z^4+z|\le |z^4|+|z|\implies |z|^4 + |z|\ge 2$$

---

**My deal with the question:-**

Now I did think that this inequality can hold only when $|z|\ge 1$, but I don't know why but I don't feel very comfortable with this type of proof.

So, if anyone can provide me a rigorous algebraic approach to the question. And as always more elegant solutions are welcome.

Comment: Why did you write $|z|^4+|z|\ge2$ out of nowhere? I don't see what justification you have to write that. Instead, use proof by contradiction. First assume $z$ is a solution with $|z|<1$. Then at the end conclude $|z^4+z|\le |z|^4+|z|<1+1=2$, contradicting $|z^4+z|=2$.

Comment: @arctic: If you see carefully, in my solution I clearly have stated why $|z^4+z|=2$ in the very first line.

Comment: If you see carefully, in my comment I clearly have asked why you wrote down $|z|^4+|z|\ge2$, not $|z^4+z|=2.~~$ :-)

Comment: Oh...then also still it is correct due to the property I stated in my solution, the ["Triangle inequality"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality)

Comment: You mean $2=|z^4+z|\le |z|^4+|z|$? (If you're just starting out with proofs, you'll want the equations you write down to clearly indicate which properties are being used.) Yes, that's correct, but where could you go from there? [Also, this question doesn't seem to have anything to do with algebraic geometry.]

Comment: @arctictern: I did state the property I used in my solution, and about the tag I just thought that it relates with the solutions lying outside the circle(there a geometrical figure), so I tagged it because I thought that only one tag doesn't look good :-P. If its not appropriate I will remove it immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $|z| \lt 1$ then $|z|^4 \le |z| \lt 1$ therefore $|z|^4 + |z| \lt 1 + 1=2$ which contradicts the inequality $|z|^4 + |z|\ge 2$

Comment: Okay, that was really easy, why didn't I think of that, if possible can you also provide any other kind of solution that you can come up with.

Comment: @user350331 Are you familiar with Rouché's theorem?